# How to get first missing number out 100 from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

hi i have created watch points in this columns 1,2,3,4,5.....100  will come

Example:  1,2,4,5,34,56,100
from above 3 is missing first this number should return

```
$watchPoints            =   $videoWatchedData['watch_points'];
$fetArray = explode(",",$watchPoints);  //unsorted 2,4,5,100,56,1,34
```

i want to sort the above one like this 1,2,4,5,34,56,100 and return first missing number.

What i have tried:

```
$sortFetchedArraysort   =   sort($fetArray ); //ksort,rosrt no one is working


$Expected = 1;
foreach ($sortFetchedArraysort as  $Number){
    if ($Expected != $Number)   {
        break;
    }
    $Expected++;
}
$percentageCount = $Number; // first missing number in my case output should return 3
exit;
```

> Two problem i am facing one is sort not working second first missing number is not trturning.

Comment: Please define "sort not working." What do you get as a result?

Comment: Sort does not return the array, it operates on the array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware then what is my solution now.?

Comment: Change `$sortFetchedArraysort   =   sort($sortFetchedArraysort);` to just `sort($sortFetchedArraysort);`

Comment: Replace the line `$sortFetchedArraysort = sort($sortFetchedArraysort);` by `sort($sortFetchedArraysort);` if `$sortFetchedArraysort` contains your array, and not `$fetArray` as in your question.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed check my [simple answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43950719/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this simple one, will be helpful for you. In your post you are sorting `$fetArray` but there is no need, you can check it like this.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array=range(1,100);//your columns

//you should sort like this, but it is not at all required
$fetArray=array(2,4,5,100,56,1,34);
sort($fetArray);

//looping over array in which we are trying to find
foreach($array as $value)
{
    //at the moment your that value is not present in array we will break from loop
    if(!in_array($value, $fetArray))
    {
        break;
    }
}
//at the moment we break from loop we will get the value which is not present
echo $value;
```

Comment: array_diff($array,$fetArray);

Comment: @JYoThI can you give examle with that in answer

Comment: @SahilGulati can you please tell how it is triggering first missing number.  if array is like this `$fetArray=array(72,4,5,100,56,1,34);` then what will be the first out put..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Can you check it hope this will help you out.

Comment: <?php

$first = [2,4,5,100,56,1,34];

$new = range(1,100);

sort($first);

$first_one = array_diff($new,$first);

$v = array_values($first_one);

echo   $v[0];

?>

Comment: i posted it as answer can you please check it @AbdulWaheed

Comment: @JYoThI you are right friend, But In my solution i am not iterating over complete array, when a element not found, it breaks loop, You post is okay but not good in performance point of view.

Comment: i agree that performance is low but you stated that *Jyothi solution will not work* so only i posted it . cool :) @SahilGulati

Comment: cool :) and please remove sorry comment too . it's my humble request @SahilGulati

Comment: @JYoThI Did that... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144140/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-jyothi).

Answer (score 2):

Try this few code, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/793563)**.

```
<?php
  sort($array = explode(',', "10,1,2,4,5,6,25,36,75,100"));
  print_r(current(array_diff(range(1, 100), $array)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$watchPoints = "10,1,2,4,5,6,25,36,75,100";
$fetArray = explode(",", $watchPoints);
sort($fetArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fetArray); $i++) {
 if ($fetArray[$i] != $i + 1) {
    $missing = $i + 1;
    break;
 }
}
print($missing);
```